# Acumatica Web Services - Adding Crossreference alternate ID to Stock Item

Tags: rest, web-services, acumatica

We are trying to add new Alternate Id to a current Stock Item, when pushing the service body we receive the point back without any error. However, it does not add the additional Cross Reference Item.

```
{
  "InventoryID": {
    "value": "APR000195XXX"
  },
  "CrossReferences": [
    {
      "AlternateID": {
        "value": "19405"
      },
      "AlternateType": {
        "value": "Global"
      },
      "Description": {
        "value": "XXXPUL0001"
      },
      "Subitem": {
        "value": "000000"
      },
      "VendorOrCustomer": {},
      "custom": {},
      "files": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please double check that it can be added through UI with the same values for the same Inventory ID. It may be disabled for some reason.

Comment: Hi Dmitrii, we did do that as the first check, and then only incremented the AlternateID for the service check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue came down to screen rights on roles that were not set

Answer (score 0):

If you want add line Cross-Reference to existing stock Item  your request should work.
Just check that you use correct type - "PUT" and correct endpoint:

[image]

Comment: hi Yuriy, that was our first try in Postman, yet did not work. Acumatica Dev support has asked us to restart the application server to see if their might have been any cache issues